# Web Browser in Java FX

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I am just a beginner and i wanted to create a web browser in java using swing. now here are the three things that i m not able to do:

1. Dont know how to load a web page in a frame. here is my code for that:

   ```
   AddressField.getText();
   try {
       URI uri=new URI(AddressField.getText());
       URL url=uri.toURL();
       InputStream in=url.openStream();

   } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(MyBrowser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(MyBrowser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   } catch (IOException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(MyBrowser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
   ```
2. I want to put a backward button to get back to previous page. I tried to do that but i doesnt worked well. i need a good code to get back button in function. here is the code for its action listener:

   ```
    ActionListener ab = new ActionListener() {
       @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           int i= store.size();
           loadURL(store.get(i-2).toString());//store is object of ArrayList

       }
   };
   ```
3. I also want to put an option to open a new tab and also show record of history of pages visited.

hoping for positive responses. every help will be appreciated. thank you

Comment: Are you attempting to use Swing, or JavaFX? These are two different APIs entirely.

Comment: If you use JavaFX there is a built-in browser component so you don't need to do much more than using it: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm

Comment: *"hoping for positive responses."*  Hoping for a question.  And by that I mean ***one*** question, as opposed to 3 cases of "I want..".  SO is not a "one-stop fix my code shop", it is a Q&A site.

Comment: @Tom G: i m using swing with javaFx.

Comment: @assylias: what about swing??

Comment: @AndrewThompson: sir with due respect i wanted answers only. i have read here many question and answers in which people actually ask to fix their code. so please dont point in such a rude manner.

Comment: @AndrewThompson was merely suggesting that one specific question with a clear description of the problem has more chance of getting a decent answer then posting 3 questions in one go, and posting minimalistic code hoping that we write the code for you. [This](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) might be a good read as well

Comment: ohh.. Sorry i misunderstood it since it was rude. but i just wanted to get help of all my problems at one place otherwise it would have been scattered.

Comment: @MuddassirIqbal You tagged your question with Swing and JavaFX - if you can use both, JavaFX will be a lot simpler. If you want a swing solution I suggest you removed the JavaFx tag.

Comment: *"..i just wanted to get help of all my problems at one place"*  SO has no facility to cater to your overblown self of self entitlement.  To fix that problem, consult a therapist.

Answer (score 0):

a) From [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm) it looks like you can just get the *webEngine* from the *WebView* instance and load the URL.

```
final WebView browser = new WebView();
final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

// that should do it...
webEngine.load(url.toExternalForm());
```

b) There seems to be [history support built-in](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#getHistory%28%29).
You'll just need to navigate between items...

c) As stated previously, Web History support seems to be built-in. For tabs, you'll likely need to have a [TabPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TabPane.html) (each tab with its one [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) component).